# General url shortener decoder library for PHP

Tags: php, bit.ly, url-shortener, tinyurl, goo.gl

Is there any kind of library for PHP which can decode tinyurl, Goo.gl, bit.ly and other url shortened urls without making CURL requests?

Comment: They are not encoded, the urls are just unique identifiers on those services. There is no way to 'decode' them, you can only follow them to see where they land. You don't _have_ to use curl, but some HTTP requests will be necessary, with whichever method you prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> without making CURL requests

- No

With URL shortening the hashes created have no relevancy to the URL being shortened but mealy a simple elegant internal database identifier.

The only way to retrieve the URL location is to ask the link shortening site to process the request and then catch the response data, the only way to do that is with networking to that site.

Unless the hash for the location is a reversible hash of long URL, there is no other way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

No. It isn't possible. I created small pack of function which works on most hosts.

```
<?php
class url{
        function get_location_header($url){
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
                $response = curl_exec ($ch);
                curl_close ($ch);
                preg_match("~(http://.*)~", $response, $match);
                return $match[0];
        }

        function cache_save($file, $content){
                $f = fopen('cache/'.$file, 'w+');
                fwrite($f, $content);
                fclose($f);
        }

        function long_url($short_url){
                $patterns = array('goo\.gl', 'tinyurl\.com', 'bit\.ly');
                $header = $this->get_location_header($short_url);
                if ($header){
                        $long_url = $header;
                        return $long_url;
                }
        }
}

$url = new url();
echo $url->long_url('http://goo.gl/0A3kH').'<br />';
echo $url->long_url('http://tinyurl.com/5b2su2').'<br />';
echo $url->long_url('http://bit.ly/4Agih5');
```

it is with curl but it isn't possible to do it without CURL/network

Comment: Thats still using networking, when he said without curl, he would specifically meant the connection to that service, using copy uses the networking protocols just like curl

Comment: Removed my down vote as I understand that the question he presented was not clear enough

Comment: That is the answer he was probably looking for :)

Comment: @genesis: It'd be safer to match `^Location:\s*(http.+)$` to get the redirection url. You never know if they put some `X-*` header in there that also contains a url (and yours won't match "https" either). Also, you might want to do some error checking (http status in the 30x range, curl worked, and preg_match'ed). It's nit-picky I admit, but I'd prefer to just get NULL and not a warning back if a short url has been mistyped.

Answer (score 2):

At least bit.ly and TinyURL just uses HTTP redirects.

So you can just get the Location response header. You can use PEAR `HTTP_Request2` for example. I don't know if *all* services use this method, but it is the most obvious one to use...

I'm not sure why you don't want to use curl. Are you talking about curl in specific or networking libraries in general? Getting information from a webpage without connecting to it seems rather non-sensical to me :-)

This is the "minimal effort quick 'n dirty" method that doesn't use a library... (You can `grep` for the `Location` header) ... You can accomplish the same using sockets...

```
[~]% telnet tinyurl.com 80
Trying 64.62.243.89...
Connected to tinyurl.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /69gb3gl HTTP/1.1             
Host: tinyurl.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.6
Location: http://www.thinkwithportals.com/media_17.php
X-tiny: db 0.1608510017395
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2011 00:45:59 GMT
Server: TinyURL/1.6

Connection closed by foreign host.


[~]% telnet bit.ly 80 
Trying 168.143.172.53...
Connected to bit.ly.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /nm0ZIh HTTP/1.1
Host: bit.ly

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2011 00:47:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: _bit=4e374910-002c2-05b82-d5ac8fa8;domain=.bit.ly;expires=Sat Jan 28 19:47:12 2012;path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-control: private; max-age=90
Location: http://richarddawkins.net/videos/642324-iq2-shorts-stephen-fry-vs-ann-widdecombe-catholic-church-debate
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 195
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have your own copy of the shortner service's database, you *have* to make some kind of request. If not to the shortened url itself, then to some API of the service. Well, actually, requesting the short url and getting the redirection header *is* technically an API, I suppose.

So I'd say cURL it. Don't follow redirects, and make sure you set cURL to return the headers (because there's nothing else). You're looking for the `Location: ....` header